# Proof of this definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Saw this sometime in my calculus book, from the Putnam Math Challenges listed:

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \underbrace{\dots}_{n-3 \, times} \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \cos ^{2} { \left\{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2n } \left({x}_{1}+{ x }_{ 2 }+\dots +{ x }_{ n }\right)\right\}  \quad { dx }_{ 1 }{ dx }_{ 2 }\cdots { dx }_{ n } }  }  }  } = \dfrac{1}{2} } $$

Thank you to whoever can help me understand this! : )

Comment: @avid19 Thanks for the LaTeX help!

Comment: **Hint:** $~\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}n=\frac{a+b}2,~$ for $~x_k\in(a,b).$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the transformation $y_1 = 1 - x_1, y_2 = 1 - x_2,\ldots, y_n= 1 - x_n$, your integral becomes

$$\int_0^1\cdots \int_0^1 \cos^2\left\{\frac{\pi}{2n}(n - y_1 - \cdots - y_n)\right\}\, dy_1\ldots dy_n,$$

which is the same as

$$\int_0^1\cdots \int_0^1 \sin^2\left\{\frac{\pi}{2n}(y_1+\cdots + y_n)\right\}\, dy_1\ldots dy_n.$$

So your integral is equal to

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\cdots \int_0^1 \left[\cos^2\left\{\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)\right\} + \sin^2\left\{\frac{\pi}{2n}(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)\right\}\right]\, dx_1\cdots dx_n,$$

which reduces to $1/2$. That's why the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: Simple and clear, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{i=0}^nx_i\right) = \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{i=0}^nx_i\right)+1}{2} = \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{i=0}^nx_i\right)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}
$$

thus
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1..\int_0^1\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{i=0}^nx_i\right)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}dx_1..dx_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{x_1..x_n}\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{i=0}^nx_i\right)}{2}dx_1..dx_n + \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1..\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}dx_1..dx_n
$$
then
$$
\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{i=0}^nx_i\right) = \mathcal{Re}\left(\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{i=0}^nx_i}\right) = \mathcal{Re}\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n}\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{n}x_i}\right)
$$
thus the integral
$$
\int_{x_1..x_n}\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{i=0}^nx_i\right)}{2}dx_1..dx_n = \int_{x_1..x_n}\mathcal{Re}\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n}\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{n}x_i}\right)dx_1..dx_n = \mathcal{Re}\left[\int_0^1\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{n}x_1}dx_1..\int_0^1\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{n}x_n}dx_n\right]
$$
where we have
$$
\int_0^1\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{n}x_n}dx_n = -i\frac{n}{\pi}\left[\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{n}}-1\right]\\
 \lim_{n\to\infty}-i\frac{n}{\pi}\left[\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\pi}{n}}-1\right] = -i\frac{n}{\pi}\left[\mathrm{e}^{0}-1\right] = 0
$$
(note this limit should be proven more rigorously, I have assumed that the exponential tends to one faster than $n\to \infty$)

thus the only nonzero is the integral
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1..\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}dx_1..dx_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1dx_1..\int_0^1 dx_n = \frac{1}{2}1\cdot1...\cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: An interesting approach, although I can't understand everything within it, this different path shows and interesting link between imaginary numbers and trig functions once more! :)

Comment: no worries..to be honest there is a step in the limit which I have not proven  rigorously. I am glad you went with the other post :).

Comment: After staring about your solution for about 5 minutes, I realized that I do understand this method through complex numbers, it just looks more complex than I thought it would be. Thank you so much nonetheless! :)

Comment: We will see if it stands up to the peer review :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced the following is correct. However why not just

$$s_1 = \frac 1n (x_1 + \dots + x_n), s_2 = x_2, \dots, s_n = x_n$$?

The integral becomes

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dots \int_0^1 \cos^2(\pi s_1 / 2)\cdot \frac 1n \ \ \ ds_1 \dots ds_n = \frac 12$$

So it appears to be true always not just as $n \to \infty$